# Http get request for Wowza Streaming Engine - Incoming Streams

Tags: stream, wowza

I need to get the the names of the incoming streams from wowza streaming engine.

[Incoming Streams page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O8H0.png)

I tried to make a request but I can't find an API to that path.

I can only get to the main page of the app using this:

`import requests`
`from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth`
`response = requests.get('http://'+url+':8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/{appName}', headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(user, password))`

Thanks.